# Model comparison in PyMC3

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3, model-comparison

I am new to PyMC3 and am trying to implement the hierarchical model from Kruschke (2015) section 12.2.2 (model comparison).

I succeeded in defining the full model and then looking at the differences of posterior parameter values (determine whether difference can credibly be said to be zero).

I also tried to explicitly do the comparison in the model as shown in the book (defining a full model and a restricted model and sampling these using a categorical distribution).

Basically I try to implement the below JAGS model definition in PyMC3.
http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/JWarmenhoven/DBDA-python/blob/master/Notebooks/Chapter%2012.ipynb
But I don't know how I can use the model index to select the (pseudo) priors. Any pointers?

JAGS:

```
model {
  for ( s in 1:nSubj ) {
    nCorrOfSubj[s] ~ dbin( theta[s] , nTrlOfSubj[s] )
    theta[s] ~ dbeta( aBeta[CondOfSubj[s]] , bBeta[CondOfSubj[s]] ) 
  }

  for ( j in 1:nCond ) {
    # Use omega[j] for model index 1, omega0 for model index 2:
    aBeta[j] <-       ( equals(mdlIdx,1)*omega[j] 
                      + equals(mdlIdx,2)*omega0  )   * (kappa[j]-2)+1
    bBeta[j] <- ( 1 - ( equals(mdlIdx,1)*omega[j] 
                      + equals(mdlIdx,2)*omega0  ) ) * (kappa[j]-2)+1
    omega[j] ~ dbeta( a[j,mdlIdx] , b[j,mdlIdx] )
  }

  omega0 ~ dbeta( a0[mdlIdx] , b0[mdlIdx] )
  for ( j in 1:nCond ) {
    kappa[j] <- kappaMinusTwo[j] + 2
    kappaMinusTwo[j] ~ dgamma( 2.618 , 0.0809 ) # mode 20 , sd 20
  }
  # Constants for prior and pseudoprior:
  aP <- 1
  bP <- 1
  # a0[model] and b0[model]
  a0[1] <- .48*500       # pseudo
  b0[1] <- (1-.48)*500   # pseudo 
  a0[2] <- aP            # true
  b0[2] <- bP            # true
  # a[condition,model] and b[condition,model]
  a[1,1] <- aP           # true
  a[2,1] <- aP           # true
  a[3,1] <- aP           # true
  a[4,1] <- aP           # true
  b[1,1] <- bP           # true
  b[2,1] <- bP           # true
  b[3,1] <- bP           # true
  b[4,1] <- bP           # true
  a[1,2] <- .40*125      # pseudo
  a[2,2] <- .50*125      # pseudo
  a[3,2] <- .51*125      # pseudo
  b[1,2] <- (1-.40)*125  # pseudo
  b[2,2] <- (1-.50)*125  # pseudo
  b[3,2] <- (1-.51)*125  # pseudo
  b[4,2] <- (1-.52)*125  # pseudo
  # Prior on model index:
  mdlIdx ~ dcat( modelProb[] )
  modelProb[1] <- .5
  modelProb[2] <- .5
}
```

PyMC3:

```
with pmc.Model() as model_1:
    # constants
    aP, bP = 1, 1

    # Pseudo- and true hyperpriors per model
    a0 = [.48*500, aP]      
    b0 = [(1-.48)*500, bP]  

    # Lower level pseudo- and true priors per model/condition combination
    a = np.c_[np.tile(aP, 4), [(.40*125), (.50*125), (.51*125), (.52*125)]]
    b = np.c_[np.tile(bP, 4), [(1-.40)*125, (1-.50)*125, (1-.51)*125, (1-.52)*125]]

    # Prior on model index [0,1]
    m_idx = pmc.Categorical('m_idx', np.asarray([.5, .5]))

    # Priors on concentration parameters
    kappa = pmc.Gamma('kappa', 2.618, 0.0809, shape=nCond)

    # omega0 
    omega0 = pmc.Beta('omega0', a0[m_idx], b0[m_idx])    

    # omega (condition specific)
    omega = pmc.Beta('omega', a[:,m_idx], b[:,m_idx], shape=nCond)

    # theta
    aBeta = pmc.switch(eq(m_idx, 0), omega0 * kappa[cond_idx]+1, omega[cond_idx] * kappa[cond_idx]+1)
    bBeta = pmc.switch(eq(m_idx, 0), (1-omega0) * kappa[cond_idx]+1, (1-omega[cond_idx]) * kappa[cond_idx]+1)

    theta = pmc.Beta('theta', aBeta[cond_idx], bBeta[cond_idx], shape=df.index.size)

    # Likelihood
    y = pmc.Binomial('y', n=df.nTrlOfSubj.values, p=theta, observed=df.nCorrOfSubj)    




Applied log-transform to kappa and added transformed kappa_log_ to model.
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-74e77ccc6ce9> in <module>()
      8 
      9     # omega0
---> 10     omega0 = pmc.Beta('omega0', a0[m_idx], b0[m_idx])
     11 
     12     # omega (condition specific)

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not FreeRV
```

**UPDATED**
After correcting the pseudopriors (missing parenthesis) the results look much better. However, I am not sure whether the pmc.Beta() function works well with arrays as arguments for a and b.
http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/JWarmenhoven/DBDA-python/blob/master/Notebooks/Chapter%2012.ipynb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you are trying to index a list using a tensor. One way to solve this will be to turn the list into a tensor.

```
import theano.tensor as tt
a0 = tt.as_tensor([.48*500, aP])
```

Alternatively you can use `pmc.switch()` to choose between priors and pseudopriors, something like:

```
a0 = pm.switch(m_idx, .48*500, aP)
```

I did not check your code thoroughly, but notice you have

```
pmc.switch(eq(m_idx, 0)....)
```

Instead, you should write

```
pmc.switch(pmc.eq(m_idx, 0)....)
```

or may be:

```
pmc.switch(m_idx)....)
```

Since 0 evaluates as `False` and 1 evaluates as `True`.

Also you have

```
omega = pmc.Beta('omega0'...)
```

And you should have

```
omega = pmc.Beta('omega'...)
```

Your question made me realize I forgot to [port](https://github.com/aloctavodia/Doing_bayesian_data_analysis) a pseudoprior example. I will do it ASAP.

**EDITED**

Here if the full model

```
with pmc.Model() as model_1:

# constants
aP, bP = 1., 1.

# Pseudo- and true hyperpriors per model
a0 = tt.as_tensor([aP, .48*500])    
b0 = tt.as_tensor([bP, (1-.48)*500])

# Lower level pseudo- and true priors per model/condition combination
a = tt.as_tensor(np.c_[[(.40*125), (.50*125), (.51*125), (.52*125)], np.tile(aP, 4)])
b = tt.as_tensor(np.c_[[((1-.40)*125), ((1-.50)*125), ((1-.51)*125), ((1-.52)*125)], np.tile(bP, 4)])

# Prior on model index [0,1]
m_idx = pmc.Categorical('m_idx', p=np.array([.5, .5]))

# Priors on concentration parameters
kappa = pmc.Gamma('kappa', 2.618, 0.0809, shape=nCond)

# omega0 
omega0 = pmc.Beta('omega0', a0[m_idx], b0[m_idx])    

# omega (condition specific)
omega = pmc.Beta('omega', a[:,m_idx], b[:,m_idx], shape=nCond)

# theta
aBeta = pmc.switch(pmc.eq(m_idx, 0), omega0 * kappa+1, omega * kappa+1)
bBeta = pmc.switch(pmc.eq(m_idx, 0), (1-omega0) * kappa+1, (1-omega) * kappa+1)

theta = pmc.Beta('theta', aBeta, bBeta, shape=nCond)

# Likelihood
y = pmc.Binomial('y', n=df.nTrlOfSubj.values, p=theta[cond_idx], observed=df.nCorrOfSubj)
trace = pmc.sample(1000)
```

Notice that your code had several issues, like missing parenthesis in the definition of the variable `b` and the order of the prior and pseudopriors was inverted. Additionally I change the code in ordet to let `aBeta`, `bBeta` and `theta`have shape=nCond, and then in the likellihood define `p` as `p=theta[cond_idx]`.

I did not check the results against Kruschke's book, but the trace look reasonable.

Comment: Thanks, defining these priors as tensor constants made the model compile. (I am rather new to the details of Theano) But there is still something wrong with the indexing of these constansts using the model index `m_idx`. That variable does not change value when sampling.

Comment: I defined the priors as you suggested: enclosing the prior constants a, b, a0, b0 with 'tt.as_tensor()'. Rest of the model unchanged.

Comment: Yikes...I completely misses those mistakes! Will check as soon as possible and report back.

Comment: I don't think that the order of the priors/pseudopriors for _a_ & _b_ had been inverted. They are used for the condition specific omega parameter, which corresponds to model 0. So when model index is 0, then the true priors should be used (first column). When index is 1, use pseudopriors in second column.

Comment: Hi @Jordi. When m_idx is 0 the switch function will select omega0 for defining aBeta and bBeta and hence you will need the true priors for omega0 and the pseudopriors for omega. When model is 1 is the other way around.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. I had the switch function arguments mixed up in my initial question. In my updated version I made it comparable to Kruschke: the first model (index 0 in Python) is the condition specific model, the second model is the one that uses omega0 for all conditions.
Thanks for your help.